# Evaluating a combined string including NA

Tags: r, eval, paste, na

My aim is to code TRUE/FALSE evaluating a string generated from pasting three character cells. The following is what I have.

```
cond.var<-"a"
relation<-"!="
cond.value<-"1"  
a<-1

as.numeric(eval(parse(text=paste(cond.var, relation, cond.value, sep=""))))
```

The above codes work when a number is stored in cond.value. The last line returns 0, which is correct. Yet, when NA is stored in cond.value (cond.value<-"NA"), the last line returns just NA, which is incorrect.

Any suggestion to fix this problem will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite hackish but this would work without changing your setting
(using `magrittr`-pipe to improve readability)

```
library(magrittr)

paste("`", relation, "`(", cond.var, ", ", cond.value, ")", sep="") %>% 
    sub(paste0(cond.var, ", NA)"), paste0("is.na(", cond.var, "), TRUE)"), .) %>% 
    parse(text=.) %>% 
    eval() %>% 
    as.numeric()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another function to compare whether two items are identical, e.g. `identical()`:

```
> identical(1, 1)
TRUE
> identical(1, NA)
FALSE
> identical(1, 0)
FALSE
> identical(NA, NA)
TRUE
```

Though this makes the `relation` variable a bit less universal to use.

So the full solution would be:

```
cond.var<-"a"
relation<-"!identical"
cond.value<-"1"  
a<-1

as.numeric(eval(parse(text=paste0(relation, '(', cond.var, ',', cond.value, ')'))))
```

Comment: This code is great, but changing to "!identical" requires other parts of the whole codes. Yet, I really appreciate your time to help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I figured you were keen to keep the `relation` variable in the original format :)

Answer (score 0):

The premise of your question (that `a != NA` returning NA is incorrect) is in fact wrong.

NA is, literally, "not available." Not `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but unknown. So if I ask you, "is an unknown value equal to 1?" your answer would be, quite reasonably, "Unknown." Most logical operations on an NA value, such as asking if NA is equal to 1, return NA (there are some exceptions, such as the obvious `is.na(NA)` or `identical(NA, NA)` as mentioned in another answer).

Thus, if NA is plugged into your original code:

```
cond.var<-"a"
relation<-"!="
cond.value<-"NA"  
a<-1

as.numeric(eval(parse(text=paste(cond.var, relation, cond.value, sep=""))))
```

...that last command should, in fact return NA. Your code works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand the logic, so I guess my question was somewhat poorly addressed. Thanks.